# Can we use perl or python instead of Ruby in chef

Tags: chef-infra

Is it necessary to learn Ruby to work in chef or can we use perl or pyrhon to create recepies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at least a bit. The domain specific language which is used to express your desire is based on Ruby.

For simple recipes, you usually don't use any Ruby code, but you only declare the resource.

Once you need a bit more complex logic, you will introduce smaller parts of ruby code.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Other than a hilarious hack I made years ago as a proof of concept, yes you must use Ruby.

Comment: If you don't mind asking a follow up question,I have idea on perl,python so I can learn Ruby faster??

Comment: yes, when you can program in one of these languages, you don't have to be afraid of using Ruby.